# Tasks do Gulp com parâmetros de linha de comando

Tags: javascript, gulp, linha-de-comando, gulpjs

Trabalho com uma simples *task* do `Gulp`, criada para realizar um *deploy* em ambiente de produção. De uma maneira simplificada, a *task* é:

```
gulp.task('deploy-prod', function () {
    return gulp.src('dist/**')
        .pipe(sftp({
            host: '000.000.000.000',
            user: 'user',
            pass: 'pass',
            remotePath: '/var/www/html/meusite/',
            port: 22
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

que eu rodo com o com

```
$ gulp deploy-prod
```

Existe um outro ambiente (de homologação) que, obviamente, possuí endereço e credenciais diferentes. Para este, possuo uma *task* chamada `deploy-homolog`, cuja lógica é a mesma. Este é apenas um caso, dentre tantos outros, onde acabo tendo que repetir o código das minhas *tasks* por apresentarem características levemente diferentes em dados momentos do desenvolvimento.

Minha pergunta é: existe uma maneira de parametrizar a execução dessas *tasks*, via linha de comando? Minha intenção era rodar

```
$ gulp deploy --prod
```

ou

```
$ gulp deploy --homolog
```

e ter apenas uma *task* `deploy`, que executaria uma rotina baseada nesta flag. Isso é possível? Se sim, como?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por padrão o gulp não aceita parâmetros dessa forma, mas, você pode utilizar o módulo [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) para trabalhar com estes argumentos (existem diversos módulos para esta situação).

Vou utilizar um exemplo simples mas que pode ser usado para resolver o seu problema, segue o código:

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
    yargs = require('yargs'),
    args = yargs.argv;

gulp.task(
    'default',
    function () {
        if (args.prod) {
            console.log('Production tasks are running.');
        }
        if (args.dev) {
            console.log('Development tasks are running');
        }
    }
);
```

Agora, você pode executar as tarefas em produção com o comando `gulp --prod`, ou, as tarefas em desenvolvimento com o `comando gulp --dev` por exemplo.

**Edição**

Vou adicionar uma segunda forma de se obter o mesmo resultado, mas sem o uso de um novo módulo/dependência. Veja como fica:

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task(
  'deploy',
  function () {
    var production = process.argv.indexOf('--production') !== -1;

    if (production) {
      console.log('Running production tasks.');
    }
    if (! production) {
      console.log('Running development tasks.');
    }
  }
);
```

Agora você pode executar o `gulp deploy --production` para rodar as tarefas de produção, ou executar o `gulp deploy`, para rodar as tarefas de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Boa resposta! O uso de mais um módulo não me agrada muito, mas resolve o problema. Vamos ver se mais alguém aparece com uma resposta diferente. Por ora, +1

Comment: Entendo a sua implicância com o uso de vários módulos/dependências, adicionei um segundo exemplo a minha resposta anterior, espero ter ajudado, abraços.

Comment: Perfeito, é isso aí.